# How to create file using script task in ssis with format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt

Tags: c#, sql

how to create a text file of the format Employee_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt using script task and everytime we run that task the seconds should increment

Comment: Are you trying to build that string in C# or T-SQL?

Comment: is that all you have..? or do you actually have relevant code to support your question..? if not please start coding something before expecting others to just give you an answer / do your work for you..

Comment: i am trying to build that string in c#

Answer (score 3):

```
    string Filename = "Employee_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(Filename);
    Writer.WriteLine("Line");
    Writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could build that string like this:

```
var fileName = string.Format("Employee_{0}.txt",
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

and in T-SQL you could get that string by doing this:

```
SELECT 'Employee_'
    + CAST(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(day, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(second, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
    + '.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help..